# How to conditionally return from an async method returning Task?

Tags: c#, async-await, return

I have the following function:

```
    Task LoadResourcesAsync(IReadOnlyList<StorageFile> files)
    {
        if (files is null)
        {
            return;    // This will throw an error
        }

        if (files.Count == 0)
        {
            return;    // This will throw an error
        }

        // Some asynchronous code here that loads resources
    }
```

What I would like to do is return from this function *before* loading resources based on some checks on the input parameters. But since the function is asynchronous, how do I indicate that "*I'm done here?*". My task is completed and I want to exit, how do I return this task which is completed?

Comment: if you method is async, just return, if not do return Task.CompletedTask

Comment: @GrayCat The doc of ```Task.CompletedTask``` says that it "Gets a task that has already completed successfully." It was actually unclear to me what task is it talking about. But I think I get it now. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `LoadResourcesAsync` was marked `async`, then you would just `return;`.

Since it doesn't appear to be (meaning: it isn't async itself, but proxies to async methods): you need to return a task that *is completed*. Fortunately, one exists conveniently;

```
return Task.CompletedTask;
```